# Android animating a compound component on a loop

Tags: android, animation, custom-component

I am quite new to Android but I have a fair amount of experience in the XAML space when it comes to UI and mobile devices.

I want to create a scene where when a user clicks a button/types a command, I add a new compound component to my scene, but not only this I want to animate its X/Y coordinates into its desired positions onto the screen. My compound component is made up of a an `ImageView` and a `TextView` and is only around 125x125 in size.

My question is, what is the best/common method for creating a looping `Thread` in Android such that I can iterate over X number of Compound Components in my scene and incrementally change their X/Y coordinates?

I have seen some people simply extend `Thread` but these all seem to be in conjunction with a `SurfaceView` which I was hoping to avoid using (for simplicity).

Comment: use a Handler to simulate a loop

Comment: How do I do that? I have searched around and there doesnt seem to be much out there!

Comment: http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-developmentthreading-part-1-handlers/

Comment: So essentially, I just run a loop with a .sleep call which then calls the UI thread to update each element on the screen? Seems very archaic...

Comment: no, use a Handler and its one of *Delayed* method, no need for extra Thread